# Windows FTP client with autoreconnect and resume download feature

Tags: ftp, software-rec

I'm looking for Windows FTP client with ability of auto reconnect if connection failed and auto resume downloading after successfully reconnecting. Also it is strongly needed that this software could support multiple connections mode (downloading files from same FTP in several connections).

Is any such miracle? Even paid version will be very well.

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP can do this. I just tested it (to be sure) ;)

https://winscp.net/

Comment: I've used `WinSCP` (5.2.x), but it failed to do this: for uknown reasons program crushes after trying to download using 9 parallel threads in it.

Comment: @Andremoniy WinSCP 5.2.x is a two years old beta branch. Did you try the latest stable version?